# Memcached ruby gem error lib sasl on Angstrom

Tags: ruby, rubygems, memcached, angstrom-linux

i'm trying to use memcached gem on a project on linux angstrom.

I'm doing bundle install on my ruby project and it will start to download and install all rubygem necessary.

gem 'eventmachine'
gem 'serialport'
gem 'memcached'
gem 'json'
gem 'activerecord'
gem 'sqlite3'

but when memcached load i see this error:

```
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for sasl/sasl.h... no
Please install SASL to continue. The package is called libsasl2-dev on Ubuntu and cyrus-sasl on Gentoo.
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=/usr/local/bin/ruby


Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/memcached-1.7.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/memcached-1.7.0/ext/gem_make.out
```

In ubuntu i solved using: apt-get install libsasl2 but on angstrom i've not libsasl2 on opkg, in fact opkg install libsasl2 fail.

How to solve? Thanks.